# crypto privateDecrypt in client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I developed a web application with Express and React for doing online exams using asymmetric cryptography to be secure. it must encrypt the question object sending to client side then decrypt it using user's privateKey. user's answers also must be encrypted then sending to server side. 
I used crypto node module in client side and it works only for symmetric enc/dec not asymmetric and says `Unable to decrypt data`. I found some npm module for client side but not worked and those are unable to decrypt data (privateDecrypt). also, I tried using WebCryptoApi but it ends with just DOMException error.

if you can, please help me to find a way to do this.

**UPDATE (CODE)**

examController.js

```
static examStarted(req, res) {
let userInfo = this._userToken(req, res);
console.log(userInfo);
let examID = 1;
exam
  .findAll({
    attributes: ["id", "idCourse", "totalQuestion"],
    where: {
      id: examID,
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: userRegisterToExam,
        attributes: ["id"],
        required: true,
        where: {
          idUser: userInfo.id,
        },
      },
      {
        model: course,
        attributes: ["id"],
        required: true,
        include: [
          {
            model: question,
            required: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  })
  .then((responses) => {
    const array = [];
    const MyQuestion = [];
    const questionInfo = [];
    const lenghtofQuestion = Object.keys(responses[0].course.questions)
      .length;
    console.log(lenghtofQuestion);
    const info = responses[0].course.questions;

    //this.generateQuestion(req, res, queryResult1[0].idCourse)
    for (let total = 0; total <= responses[0].totalQuestion - 1; total++) {
      const count = this.RandomInt(lenghtofQuestion, array);
      console.log(count);
      MyQuestion[total] = info[count];
      questionInfo.push({
        idExamStart: 0,
        idQuestion: info[count].id,
        response: 5,
        status: 0,
      });
      array.push(count);
    }
    //console.log(responses[0].userRegisterToExam)

    this.startTest(
      req,
      res,
      MyQuestion,
      questionInfo,
      examID,
      responses[0].userRegisterToExams[0].id
    );
  })
  .catch((error) => this.SetErrorInfo(req, res, error));
}
static startTest(
req,
res,
MyQuestion,
questionInfo,
examID,
idUserRegisterToExam
) {
let userInfo = this._userToken(req, res);
let password = "milad"; //userInfo.id + "-" + this.generateRandomString();
console.log("pass1", password);
let key = this.generateKeys(password);
let publicKey = key.publicKey;
let privateKey = key.privateKey;
let data = {
  idUser: userInfo.id,
  idExam: examID,
  idUserRegisterToExam,
  dateStart: this.getDate("jYYYY/jMM/jDD h:m:s"),
  dateUpload: "",
  teacherConfirmation: "0",
  supervisorConfirmation: "0",
  score: "0",
  document: "0",
  status: "0",
  public: publicKey,
  private: privateKey,
  password,
};
examStart
  .create(data)
  .then((responses) => {
    let tokenString = {
      userID: userInfo.id,
      start: responses.id,
      password,
      privateKey,
    };
    let d = this.encryption(
      JSON.stringify(MyQuestion),
      publicKey,
      privateKey,
      password
    );

    let data = {
      token: this.encrypt(JSON.stringify(tokenString)),
      data: d.data,
      k: d.key,
    };
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => this.SetErrorInfo(req, res, error));
}
static encryption(toEncrypt, publicKey, privateKey, password) {
var mykey = crypto.createCipher("aes-128-cbc", password);
var mystr = mykey.update(toEncrypt, "utf8", "base64");
mystr += mykey.final("base64");
// key encryption (asymmetric)
var buffer = new Buffer(password);
var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
var enc = encrypted.toString("base64");
return { key: encrypted.toString("base64"), data: mystr };
}

static decryption(req, res) {
// decryption
// key decryption (asymmetric)
let dec = this.decrypt(req, res, req.body.token);
console.log("dec", dec);
let tokenObject = JSON.parse(dec);
let privateKey = tokenObject.privateKey;
let password = tokenObject.password; //this.decrypt(req, res, tokenObject.password);
let pass = password.toString("utf8");
let buffer = new Buffer(req.body.key, "base64");
const decryptedKey = crypto.privateDecrypt(
  {
    key: privateKey.toString(),
    passphrase: pass,
  },
  buffer
);
var symmetricKey = decryptedKey.toString("utf8");
// symmetric decryption
var mykey = crypto.createDecipher("aes-128-cbc", symmetricKey);
var mystr = mykey.update(req.body.data, "base64", "utf8");
mystr += mykey.final("utf8");
res.send({ requests: req.body, result: mystr });
}
static generateKeys(myPassword) {
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync("rsa", {
  modulusLength: 4096,
  namedCurve: "secp256k1",
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: "spki",
    format: "pem",
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: "pkcs8",
    format: "pem",
    cipher: "aes-256-cbc",
    passphrase: myPassword,
  },
});
return {
  privateKey,
  publicKey,
};
}
```

React Component (getting encrypted questions from server)

```
_getData() {
const data = {
  exam: this.state.id,
  idCourse: this.state.idCourse,
  factor: this.state.idFactor,
};

axios
  .post(`${this._ServerUrl()}examStarted`, data, {
    headers: this._Header(),
  })
  .then((response) => {
    let a = this.decrypt(response.data.token); // it's for symmetric decryption and works good.
    console.log(a);
    this.setState({
      privateKey: a.privateKey,
      password: a.password,
      getDateStatus: true,
    });
    try {
      let data = this.decryption(
        a.password,
        a.privateKey,
        response.data.data,
        response.data.k
      );
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.errorLog(error);
  });
}


decryption(password, privateKey, text, key) {
let buffer = new Buffer(key, "base64");
const decryptedKey = cryptoBrowserify.privateDecrypt(
  {
    key: privateKey.toString(),
    passphrase: password.toString(),
  },
  buffer
);
var symmetricKey = decryptedKey.toString("utf8");
// symmetric decryption
var mykey = crypto.createDecipher("aes-128-cbc", symmetricKey);
var mystr = mykey.update(text, "base64", "utf8");
mystr += mykey.final("utf8");
return mystr;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried bcrypt?

Comment: @RichardRublev bcrypt is just for hashing I think.

Comment: Hard to help if you don't post the code you're struggling with - provide examples of the server and client encryption and decryption.

Comment: @RichardRublev bcrypt is a KDF/password hash and has nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I updated question with code.

Comment: Why is the server generating the RSA key pair for encrypting the question? That makes no sense. The key pair must be generated by the *recipient* of a message, not the sender. How does the client get the private key? It's unclear how what you are trying to do is any better than TLS (i.e. HTTPS).

Comment: @Peter you mean I should generate one pair in server and one pair in client then exchange public keys ? Am I right?

Comment: Yes. But *only if* you can demonstrate what you are gaining over just using TLS, which already does everything you seem to want to achieve correctly.